# Legendre symbol trouble.

Tags: number-theory, legendre-symbol

I did the same calcultation, for the legrange symbol, twice and got two different answers. Could someone please point out where I went wrong for future reference.

1) $\bigg(\frac{79}{81}\bigg)=(-1)^{\frac{79-1}{2}\frac{81-1}{2}}\bigg(\frac{81}{79}\bigg)=+1\bigg(\frac{2}{79}\bigg)=(-1)^{\frac{79-1}{2}}=(-1)$

2) $\bigg(\frac{79}{81}\bigg)=(-1)^{40\cdot39}\bigg(\frac{81}{79}\bigg)=1\bigg(\frac{9}{79}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{9}{79}\bigg)=\bigg(\frac{3}{79}\bigg)^4=(-1)^{39\cdot1\cdot 4}\bigg(\frac{79}{3}\bigg)^4=\bigg[-\bigg(\frac{1}{3}\bigg)\bigg]^4=1 $

Comment: Sorry I forgot the square brackets, the answer should be method 2 i believe as $x^2\equiv 79\ mod\ 81$ has solutions for $x=22,\ 59$

Comment: Try evaluating (2/p) using the second, not the first supplementary law.

Comment: $\left( \frac 2{79} \right) $ is clearly $1$....$9^2\equiv 2 \pmod {79}$.

Comment: $\left( \frac 2p \right) = \left( -1 \right)^{\frac {p^2-1}8}$

Comment: Thank you Lulu, I must have a mistake in my notes, thanks for clearing that up